# Differentiate between session timeout and spring concurrency-control max sessions

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, session-timeout, session-management

I'm extending HttpSessionEventPublisher and i want in my sessionDestroyed() method to differentiate between sessions that were timed out and ones that closed because of concurrency-control max sessions.
Is there a flag in HttpSessionEvent or the authentication object?
if not can i override the session closing that the concurrency-control do?

EDIT:
I added a costume concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy but I get this error:
Configuration problem: session-authentication-strategy-ref attribute cannot be used in combination with

my security.xml:

```
<security:session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="playerConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" />
        </security:session-management>
```

PlayerConcurrentSessionControlStrategy :

```
@Component
public class PlayerConcurrentSessionControlStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
```

what to do?

Comment: You cannot, you could roughly detect a session-timeout and a session invalidation but the invalidation also occurs if someone has logged out for instance.

Comment: can I add a isClosed field to my UserDetail and override the way  concurrency-control mark that session?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This can solve 2 problems: 1. concurrency-control max sessions in a cluster tomcat env 2. i want to log the close reason of each session- time out or closed because of another session

Comment: For 1 you need a cluster/database driven `SessionRegistry` implementation, that has nothing to do with the `HttpSessionListener`. If you want to log the reason then simply extend the `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` and override the `allowableSessionsExceeded` method and do the logging in there. The actual `HttpSession` isn't invalidated only marked invalid/expired in the `SessionRegistry`

Comment: thank you! I will try it, can you point me to an example for a SessionRegistry that uses a DB?

Comment: You might want to use google, there are some hits but those are for a distributed cache based solution instead of a DB. But it shouldn't be that hard to implement.

Comment: Please add proper erorr messages and stacktraces. If you have a custom  'session-authentication-strategy-ref' you must explicitly configure it and cannot use `security:concurrency-control` anymore.